# If this month has 28 days, find all customers with a bill date of 29, 30, or 31

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a customer bill day table looking something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_billing (
    customer_name VARCHAR(20)
    ,bill_day INT
)
```

With data like

```
'ABC', 1
'DEF', 10
'GHI', 28
'JKL', 29
'MNO', 30
'PQR', 31
```

Every day, I would like to send a bill to all customers whose bill day is equal to the current day [i.e., `WHERE BILL_DAY = EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE)`].

However, if a customer's bill day is 31, but today is the last day of a month that only contains 28, 29, or 30 days, I would like to send that customer a bill today as well.

This is what I have so far. The logic works but I think there is a better way to accomplish it.

```
SELECT customer_name
FROM customer_billing
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND bill_day = (CASE 
            WHEN bill_day <=  EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) 
                THEN EXTRACT(DAY from SYSDATE) 
            WHEN  EXTRACT(DAY from SYSDATE) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
                AND bill_day > EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) 
                THEN bill_day
            END);
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly more concise version:

```
SELECT customer_name
  FROM customer_billing
 WHERE   LEAST(bill_day, EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)))
       = EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking about:

```
bill_day = EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE)
OR
(
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
    AND
    bill_day > EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
)
```